# Submitting fieldsets

Tags: forms

I have fieldsets in my form like this

```
$form['fieldset_1']['name']
```

and then

```
$form['fieldset_2']['name']
```

but when I submit the form and access the values item in $form_state there is only one name value - not as expected `['fieldset_1']['name']` and `['fieldset_2']['name']`

can someone help how the form could be submitted and to have access to bot name values ?

Comment: You should use `$form['#tree'] => TRUE` in your form if you want submitted data in tree structure.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, it helped and now the values are as they should

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`#tree`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#tree) property on both fieldsets, e.g.

```
$form['fieldset_1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Title 1'),
  '#tree' => TRUE,
);

$form['fieldset_1']['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  ...
);

$form['fieldset_2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Title 2'),
  '#tree' => TRUE,
);

$form['fieldset_2']['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  ...
);
```